# Python 3 numpy uses integer division on matrices and regular division on vectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, division, integer-division

When running the following code:

```py
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
    
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
x[1,:] = x[1,:] / 5
print(x)
y = np.array([1,2,3])
y = y / 5
print(y)
```

I get the following output:

```
3.8.6
[[1 2 3]
 [0 1 1]
 [7 8 9]]
[0.2 0.4 0.6]
```

Why does numpy / python use integer division when dividing a row in a matrix by a scalar while dividing a single row using regular division? I thought " / " division in numpy 3 was always regular?

Comment: *"Why does numpy / python use integer division when dividing a row in a matrix"* - Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: Try it with `x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],dtype=float)`.

Comment: Related:[Numpy array being rounded? subtraction of small floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732728/numpy-array-being-rounded-subtraction-of-small-floats). [How can I multiply column of the int numpy array to the float digit and stays in int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466808/how-can-i-multiply-column-of-the-int-numpy-array-to-the-float-digit-and-stays-in).

Comment: @wwii Hmm, I'd say that rather obfuscates the reason. One might think the outcome is floats because it's then dividing floats by an int.

Comment: Numpy documentation:[Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does numpy / python use integer division when dividing a row in a matrix by a scalar

It doesn't - the *symptom* you are seeing is due to the assignment.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Dividing by an integer produces an array of floats,

```
>>> z = x[1,:] / 5
>>> z
array([0.8, 1. , 1.2])
```

But assigning that array to a slice of an *integer array* causes the dtype conversion.

```
>>> x[1,:] = z
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> z.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>>
```

---

This is mentioned in the documentation - [Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays)

> Note that assignments may result in changes if assigning higher types to lower types (like floats to ints) or even exceptions (assigning complex to floats or ints):

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is in line:

```py
x[1,:] = x[1,:] / 5
```

According to numpy documentation of `dtype`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

> A numpy array is homogeneous, and contains elements described by a dtype object

So when manually assigning the row, it's taking `dtype of x matrix` into account, which is of type `dtype('int64')`.

The same will happen to you if you tried to manually assign an element to the `y` array:

```py
y = np.array([1,2,3])
y[1] = 0.5
print(y)
# this will print array([1, 0, 3])
```

> Why does numpy / python use integer division when dividing a row in a matrix by a scalar while dividing a single row using regular division?

So it's about enforcing the homogenous `dtype` of the `np.array` itself rather than `dividing a row in a matrix`, as shown in the line below:

```py
x[1] / 5
>>> array([0.8, 1. , 1.2])
```